# Linq Group By Date into New List Including Items Nested

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a report which is grouped by date and then customer with a list of records.
I currently have a list of records with a DateTime field and a Customer field.

The outcome should show the number of records per customer per day.

I'm using entity framework to get the list of records from the database.

```
IEnumerable<Record> Records = Db.GetRecords(StartDate, EndDate);
```

The Record model and Customer model look like this:

```
 public class Record
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string OrderRef { get; set; } = default!;
        public DateTime ImportTimestamp { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; } = default!;

    }

public class Customer
    {
        public short ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
        public IEnumerable<Record> Records { get; set; } = default!;
    }
```

I would like to create a list of Rows which I can then add to the view model and iterate over to produce the report.

```
public List<ReportRow> Rows;

public class ReportRow
{
     public DateTime ImportDate { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers { get; set; }         

}
```

The expected result on the page would look something like this:

01/03/2023

- Customer1

  - Record1
  - Record2
  - Record3
- Customer2

  - Record1
  - Record2
  - Record3
- Customer3

  - Record1
  - Record2
  - Record3

02/03/2023

- Customer1

  - Record1
  - Record2
  - Record3
- Customer4

  - Record1
  - Record2
  - Record3

Answer (score 0):

Use Following.  I changed to a list : public `List<Customer>` Customers { get; set; }      :

```
            List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>(); 
            var Rows = customers.SelectMany(x => x.Records.Select( y => new { date = y.ImportTimestamp, ID = x.ID, Name = x.Name, record = y}))
                .OrderBy(x => x.date)
                .GroupBy(x => x.date)
                .Select(x => x.GroupBy(y => y.ID).Select(y => new ReportRow() { ImportDate = x.Key, Customers = (List<Customer>) y}).ToList()).ToList();
```